# jQuery datepicker not working for multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to create new datepicker every time a place in google maps is selected.

```
           $(function(){$(".datepick").datepicker({
              dateFormat : "yyyy-MM-dd"
              }); 
           });

  var tomakedate = document.getElementById("fordate");
```

This is the event on which a new datepicker will be added in html.

```
                    selectedplacessize = selectedplaces.length;
                    inputcal = document.createElement("input");
                    inputcal.type = "text";
                    inputcal.name = "datepicker" + selectedplacessize;
                    inputcal.setAttribute("id","datepicker" + selectedplacessize);
                    inputcal.className = "datepick hasDatepicker";
                    tomakedate.appendChild(inputcal);
```

In browser my html with newly added datepicker looks like this.

```
         <td id="fordate"> <input type="text" id="inputlatlong" name="inputlatlong" hidden="">
         <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" class="datepick hasDatepicker">
         <input type="text" name="datepicker1" id="datepicker1" class="datepick hasDatepicker"></td>
```

input element with id#datepicker, will be there when the page loads. Everytime a place is selected on google maps, another input type with class "datepick" will be added.
There are not errors or warnings in inspect element of browser.

Edit: I have tried replacing the line:

inputcal.className = "datepick hasDatepicker"; with

inputcal.className = "datepick";

It's still not working.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!

adding the function after tomakedate.appendChild(inputcal); worked.

Comment: Glad I could help. I actually elaborated on my comment and made it an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `$('.datepick').datepicker();` *before* these elements with class `datepick` exist. New elements added *after* this line of code will *not* be converted to datepickers, as it refers only to elements that satisfy the selector *at that instant*.

The analogy I like to use for things like this is what I refer to as The Department Store analogy:

Let's say you're working at a department store. Your manager says "Go put a red sticker on everything in the toy department" - and so you do. The next day, 100 new toys come in. Immediately, your manager comes up to you and asks "Why do the new toys not have red stickers on them?"

This is similar to what you're asking here. You're converting all the elements that are currently `.datepick` to datepickers, but as new ones are created, you are not converting them.

You can modify your code to make the elements datepickers as they're created by doing the following:

```
selectedplacessize = selectedplaces.length;
inputcal = document.createElement("input");
inputcal.type = "text";
inputcal.name = "datepicker" + selectedplacessize;
inputcal.setAttribute("id","datepicker" + selectedplacessize);     
inputcal.className = "datepick hasDatepicker";
tomakedate.appendChild(inputcal);

$inputcal = $(inputcal);
$inputcal.datepicker({dateFormat : "yyyy-MM-dd"});
```